# Order of a group with all elements as self-inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is a common result that, if all elements of a group are self-inverse, then the group is Abelian. Is it necessarily finite also?

Answer (score 5):

Consider the *infinite* product of cyclic groups of order $2$: $G= C_2 \times \cdots \times C_2$.

Comment: Isn't this impossible? " This also means that no modulo multiplication group is isomorphic to a direct product of more than three copies of C_2." http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModuloMultiplicationGroup.html

Comment: Well, it is possible as you can see, it is a very obvious construction. It is not that every group has to be realized as the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ for some $n$.

Comment: Too right, too right...

Answer (score 4):

Another example is the additive group of any field of characteristic $2$, which may be infinite (*e.g.*, $\mathbf{F}_2(t)$ or $\overline{\mathbf{F}_2}$).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be finite. Indeed, for any cardinal $\kappa$, there's a group with that property of order $2^\kappa$:

Be $M$ any set of cardinality $\kappa$. Then $(\mathcal P(M),\triangle)$ is a group with this property, where $\mathcal P(M)$ is the power set of $M$, and $\triangle$ denotes the symmetric set difference.

Indeed, if you allow groups to be defined not only on sets, but also on proper classes, the [nimbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber) with nimber addition form a group with this property whose order is the cardinality of the ordinals.